# Flutter Pre-release report Issue Native crash

Tags: android, flutter

I found the following Native Crash Issue in Google's Pre-release report.

How can I find the error through this report?

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'generic/gce_x86_phone/gce_x86:9/PGR1.190916.001/5877764:userdebug/test-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'x86'
pid: 7698, tid: 8833, name: 1.raster  >>> com.*****.***** <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Abort message: 'vendor/unbundled_google/libs/ndk_translation/ndk_translation/ir/include/ndk_translation/ir/ir.h:685: CHECK failed: IsAligned(offset, GetFormatSize(format))'
    eax 00000000  ebx 00001e12  ecx 00002281  edx 00000006
    edi 00001e12  esi c6ecfb5c
    ebp c6ecfb28  esp c6ecfab8  eip ee76fbe9
backtrace:
    #00 pc 00000be9  [vdso:ee76f000] (__kernel_vsyscall+9)
    #01 pc 0001fdf8  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+40)
    #02 pc 00022e73  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+115)
    #03 pc 00006c84  /system/lib/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+292)
    #04 pc 0009f2b4  /system/lib/libndk_translation.so (ndk_translation::GetInsn::GetInsn(ndk_translation::IR*, ndk_translation::Format, unsigned int)+276)
    #05 pc 0009f100  /system/lib/libndk_translation.so (ndk_translation::IRBuilder::Get(ndk_translation::Format, unsigned int)+144)
    #06 pc 0009dd2e  /system/lib/libndk_translation.so (ndk_translation::(anonymous namespace)::InsnBuilder::Get(ndk_translation::Format, unsigned int)+46)
    #07 pc 000d0b4b  /system/lib/libndk_translation.so (ndk_translation::SemanticsDecoder::VTBL(ndk_translation::VTBL_Args const&)+363)
    #08 pc 00100568  /system/lib/libndk_translation.so (ndk_translation::ArmDecoder::TranslateThumbInsn(unsigned short const*)+86104)
    #09 pc 0009c2b6  /system/lib/libndk_translation.so (ndk_translation::(anonymous namespace)::GenerateIRHelper(ndk_translation::CompilerHooks*, unsigned int, unsigned int, ndk_translation::IR*)+1142)
    #10 pc 0009be1f  /system/lib/libndk_translation.so (ndk_translation::GenerateIR(ndk_translation::CompilerHooks*, unsigned int, ndk_translation::IR*, unsigned int*)+47)
    #11 pc 0009bbdf  /system/lib/libndk_translation.so (ndk_translation::Compile(ndk_translation::CompilerHooks*, unsigned int, ndk_translation::GuestCodeEntry*, unsigned int*, ndk_translation::MachineCode*)+143)
    #12 pc 0007a0da  /system/lib/libndk_translation.so (ndk_translation::(anonymous namespace)::Translate(ndk_translation::TranslationCache*, unsigned int, ndk_translation::GuestCodeEntry*)+378)
    #13 pc 00079f1c  /system/lib/libndk_translation.so (ndk_translation_HandleNotTranslated+300)
    #14 pc 0018db57  /system/lib/libndk_translation.so
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this issue happens only in Emulators.
Check this answer in [GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37396#issuecomment-1155331744)

Comment: Thank you. I've been wandering for a long time.